# mongodb update (inserting new field)

Tags: mongodb

I have a DB like:

```
{
    'a' : [
        { 'name' : 'john',
          'phone' : 111111
        },
        { 'name' : 'doe',
          'phone' : 222222
        },
          ],
    'b' : [
        { 'name' : 'john',
          'phone' : 111111
        },
        { 'name' : 'doe',
          'phone' : 222222
        },
          ]
}
```

now I want to add a new field, "state : 1" to all the entries (like name, phone)

any suggestions on the update clause?
I tried using $set and $addToSet, but I'm not sure about the criteria too

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the $ positional operator. See the documentation at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator